# Different between fixed array and dynamic allocated array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have some C++ function like below:

```
void fillBuffer(char* buffer, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 1;
    }
}

void fillByPointerOfBuffer(char **pBuffer, int len) {
    fillBuffer(*pBuffer, len);
}

void printBuffer(char* buffer, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d", buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

In my main program, I try some test as below:

**Test 1**:

```
char *buffer = new char[6];
fillByPointerOfBuffer(&buffer, 6);
printBuffer(buffer, 6);
delete[] buffer;
// --> It output: 111111
```

**Test 2**:

```
char buffer[6];
fillByPointerOfBuffer( (char**)(&buffer), 6);
printBuffer(buffer, 6);
// --> Exception thrown: write access violation.
```

**Test 3**:

```
char buffer[6];
char *buffer2 = buffer;
fillByPointerOfBuffer(&buffer2, 6);
printBuffer(buffer, 6);
//// --> It output: 111111
```

In Test1, pointer to dynamic allocated array is passed to function `fillByPointerOfBuffer`.
In Test2, pointer to fixed length array is passed to function `fillByPointerOfBuffer`.
In Test3, pointer to "alias" variable of fixed length array is passed to function `fillByPointerOfBuffer`.

I think that they all must be the same, but why Test1 and Test3 worked, but Test2 does not work?

Comment: Remove the error-prone C-style cast `(char**)`.  What does your compiler tell you then?  Listen to it, it knows what you need to fix.

Comment: I think that is the point. But I still confuse what is different between `char (*)[6]` and `char **`? When these value are passed as `char **pBuffer`, then operatior `*pBuffer` should return a `char*`, right?

Comment: When you use a `(char **)` typecast to explicitly force the compiler to permit a conversion to a pointer, and then modify data at the resultant address, you are in the real of undefined behaviour.   An pointer and an array are not the same thing - but can be treated *as if* they are *only* in specific circumstances.   A pointer to an array and a pointer to a pointer are not equivalent, and cannot be treated as equivalent - but you are using a typecast to force the compiler to treat them as equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @JohnZwinck, @Peter. I think I get it.
But I have additional question, Can I modify Test2 to work without creating another variable `buffer2` like Test3?